# git push - showing Invalid certificate chain in Mac OS - El Capiton

Tags: git

I have been trying to push my code on github using source tree and for some reason i get the error. 
Fatal - Unable to access SSL certificate problem : Invalid certificate chain

I have seen some post on stackoverflow which mentions to delete the expired certs from DigCert High Assurance EV root CA and download a new from their site, but all that did not work, I have also update my mac OS to El capiton (10.11.4).

Can any one please assist on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your git url in safari , this would pop up "this is invalid certificate" do you want to continue click no and proceed. This resolved my problem on my Mac.

Comment: Could you expand on this? I'm having similar problems and I'd like to understand how NOT proceeding due to an invalid SSL cert in Safari would allow you to proceed with a commit. 

Note: I assure you I am being sincere. No snark or sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this command to temporally pass the Certification Verity:

git config http.sslVerify false